# Display َthe project in windows form with full screen

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I'm programming a .net app using windows forms in visual studio, so i want to display the windows form in a full screen that the project itself fills the entire screen without spaces between it and the windows form, The question is how do I control the size of the screen so that I know exactly where I will put the components of the project (button, TextBox...)?

I changed the form properties to this:

> **FormBorderStyle**: None

> **Size**: 1920:1080(my screen size)

> Putting the project in the center of the form with the **Anchor** property None

> **WindowsState**: maximized

Is what I did right?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "project"? To me a "project" is an organizational thing for related items in a code base, used by Visual Studio. Your soo, multiple forms, the libraries it references, helper classes etc make up a project. You might have another project in the same solution that does a particular thing, like reading a CSV. A project isn't really an "on screen" thing/something that appears on, around or within a windows form

Comment: I'm talking in general so I can apply this to all the windows forms in the project, it's an electronics store sales management project with 12 forms using sql server data base and visual studio 2019

Comment: Generally if you're designing a kiosk application you control the screen size/resolution of the kiosk so you know how things will ultimately appear. For your current settings I guess you'll need to equip the kiosk hardware with a full hd screen

Answer (score 0):

Just change the WindowsState to `Maximized`, like this:

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

If you do not want a border on your form, then change the FormBoderStyle to `None`:

```
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
```